# lines starts with # and integers in .bash_history

Tags: bash-history

I see lines contains #1582696021 . Whats is this? In SIEM we use it seems like a command running by user.

Any help or documentation would be appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are timestamps. From `man bash`

```
       HISTTIMEFORMAT
              If  this  variable  is  set and not null, its value is used as a
              format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated
              with  each  history  entry displayed by the history builtin.  If
              this variable is set, time stamps are  written  to  the  history
              file  so they may be preserved across shell sessions.  This uses
              the history comment character  to  distinguish  timestamps  from
              other history lines.
```

The integer value is an epoch time - you can convert it to human readable time using `date` for example ex.

```
$ date -d @1582696021
Wed Feb 26 00:47:01 EST 2020
```